# MediaPlayer.framework: How to "translate" MPMusicRepeatModeDefault into an actual mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mpmediaplayercontroller

As is stated in Apple documents:

```
enum {
   MPMusicRepeatModeDefault,
   MPMusicRepeatModeNone,
   MPMusicRepeatModeOne,
   MPMusicRepeatModeAll
};
typedef NSInteger MPMusicRepeatMode;
```

Yet, `MPMusicRepeatModeDefault` is described as *The user’s preferred repeat mode*. Since I am writing a music player I require to know every time what is the current repeat mode, and when this is returned, what of the "actual" modes:

- `MPMusicRepeatModeNone`
- `MPMusicRepeatModeOne`
- `MPMusicRepeatModeAll`

shall be chosen? Or is there no way to get such information?

Comment: No. Since I was in fact developing a "tweak" for jailbroken iPhones, I managed to obtain that information by looking over some data into the iPod.app preference plist (located at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mobileipod.plist`), but I never found anything out really for what could be an actual app.

Comment: Have you tried to get this info via repeatMode property of the player?

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that `MPMusicRepeatModeDefault` is only used for instantiating your own player as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingMediaPlayback/UsingMediaPlayback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH100-SW1).

```
MPMusicPlayerController* appMusicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

// Use whatever the user has set in their iPod settings
// Omitting this line has no real effect because deferring to the
// user mode is the default setting for new players
[appMusicPlayer setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeDefault];
```

If you want to know what that default setting actually is, you should be able to get it from the [iPodMusicPlayer instance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MPMusicPlayerController/iPodMusicPlayer):

```
MPMusicPlayerController* iPodMusicPlayer =
    [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

MPMusicRepeatMode theDefaultMode = [iPodMusicPlayer repeatMode];
```

Comment: There are times when `-repeatMode` returns that mode.